# Can I play 2 sets of 2 cards each one of the same color to avoid a Deal Breaker?

Tags: monopoly-deal

For example: 2 groups of green color in order to avoid deal breaker, of this way the set is not completed

Answer (score 2):

No. With four of the same color, you'd have a set of 3 and one extra.

From the [compiled FAQ on BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2459561/compilation-rules-clarifications):

> If you have more properties of one color than is needed to make a complete property set, you must form as many complete sets as possible, and group the remaining properties of that color together.